# Yahoo finance REST api for historical stock data

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I can't seem to locate documentation for the following REST api (similar to):

http://**finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1**/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json

In my particular case I want to fetch historical stock quote data (daily stock quote for last 7 years so for a particular stock).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query for historical stocks by using yahoo.finance.historicaldata, which is an undocumented data table maintained by the community:

Try this on YQL console:

```
select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "GOOG" and startDate = "2012-06-06" and endDate = "2013-01-01"
```

Be warned that since this is unofficial and not maintained by Yahoo, this query is somewhat unreliable...